# Run Errors with Eclipse C/C++ IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

I just installed gcc and Eclipse C/C++ IDE but I'm having trouble using it.
I keep getting these errors. Anyone got ideas on how to fix this?
[image: I keep getting these errors. Anyone got ideas on how to fix this?]

Comment: Please show all needed information in your question itself. Textual information should be represented in textual form, not as a picture of text.

Comment: Look closer at the image you linked to... In the main Eclipse window. Isn't that a *build* error? If you have build errors, no executable will be created, and there's nothing for you to run. You should probably ask about that instead (in a new question), but before that please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

Your project seems to be one for making a windows application.
The code in your project does not match that, it is the simple code for a console application.
Create a new project, choose "Console Application" and use the same code.

Then you should be able to successfully build your program before you execute it (credits to Some programmer dude, for spotting the "build failed is not run time error").

Comment: How to make a console application? cant see it in the options.

Comment: Please describe in detail how you created the project you show in the question.

Comment: First, I created new project, C/C++ project. Then I clicked C Managed Build, and choose the project type which is empty project and  MinGW GCC as toolchain and yadayadayada theres the file. clicked build all as shown in the YT tutorials but i dont get the output i want.

Comment: I also tried the HelloWorld project beside the Empy Project but still the same.

Comment: Which Eclipse extension for C do you use and how did you install it? Your picture looks quite similar to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veO-c3Syk6M Can you spot anything you did differently? I admit by the way, that it does not show the choice "console application", the idea however stays the same, your error sounds like an attempt to build for windows, while the code seems console.

Comment: Got it! Seems my IDE is finally working fine. Thanks for the YT video and patience.